# PSQLException: ERROR: column "drink1_.id" must appear in GROUP BY clause or used in aggregate function

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, hql

I am writing a `REST` `MVC` web-application with `Spring Boot`, `Hibernate` and `PostgreSQL`. I need to get the 6 most popular drinks out of all the `carts` I have. To do this, I first wrote a `query` in `SQL`:

```sql
SELECT drink_id, sum(count) as count
FROM cart_items
GROUP BY drink_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 6
```

There is a result and this code worked well:
[image]

Since I am working with `JPA`-repositories, I decided to write the same query in `HQL`. I wrote the request, but I had to remove `LIMIT` for a while, since I didn't know how to implement it in `HQL`.

```java
@Query("select C.drink, sum(C.count) as count from CartItem C group by C.drink order by 2 DESC")
Page<Drink> getMostPopularDrinks(Pageable pageable);
```

Then I decided to write a method for the output to check what I got:
Service:

```java
public PageDTO<DrinkDTO> findAllDrinks(int page, int pageSize) {

        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize);

        Page<Drink> drinkList = cartItemRepository.getMostPopularDrinks(pageRequest);

        return new PageDTO<>(drinkMapper.drinksToDrinksDTO(drinkList));
    }
```

Controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/drinks")
public PageDTO<DrinkDTO> getAllDrinks(@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "page_size", defaultValue = "2") int pageSize) {

        return drinkService.findAllDrinks(page, pageSize);
    }
```

СartItem Entity:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "cart_items")
public class CartItem {


    @Data
    @Embeddable
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class CartId implements Serializable {

        private Long order_id;

        private Long drink_id;
    }


    /**
     * @EmbeddedId
     */
    @EmbeddedId
    private CartId cartId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
            nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "drink_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
            nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Drink drink;

    private int count;
}
```

Drink Entity:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "drink")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Drink {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private BigDecimal price;

    private String about;

    private int weight;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "packaging_id")
    private Packaging packaging;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Country country;
```

But unfortunately I got an error, I don’t know what to do!

```java
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "drink1_.id" must appear in GROUP BY clause or used in aggregate function
  Postition: 116
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2532) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2267) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:312) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:153) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:103) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar:42.2.14]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2285) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2038) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2000) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:951) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2813) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2640) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1412) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:177) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.getMostPopularDrinks(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.getMostPopularDrinks(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at ru.coffeetearea.service.DrinkService.findAllDrinks(DrinkService.java:106) ~[main/:na]
    at ru.coffeetearea.controller.DrinkController.getAllDrinks(DrinkController.java:56) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at ru.coffeetearea.security.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:33) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

NEW LOGS:

````java
2020-08-23 18:07:56.951 ERROR 6296 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        :  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [ru.coffeetearea.dto.NewDrinkDTO]. Expected arguments are: ru.coffeetearea.model.Drink, long
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: ru.coffeetearea.dto.NewDrinkDTO]
2020-08-23 18:07:56.956 ERROR 6296 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        :  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [ru.coffeetearea.dto.NewDrinkDTO]. Expected arguments are: ru.coffeetearea.model.Drink, long
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: ru.coffeetearea.dto.NewDrinkDTO]

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.DetailedSemanticException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [ru.coffeetearea.dto.NewDrinkDTO]. Expected arguments are: ru.coffeetearea.model.Drink, long
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1258) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2390) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2256) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1518) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:716) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    ```
````

Comment: Do you want only id `drink_id` of full `Drink` Entity (your sql query is only shows drink_id )?  And show us your enities

Comment: In this case, I felt like I was getting a list of drinks. Added entities to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not important for me to get exactly drinks directly from the database, you can also drink ID. After receiving the ID, I can find them in the same database, so I slightly changed my request.

```java
  @Query("select C.drink.id, sum(C.count) as count from CartItem C group by C.drink order by 2 DESC")
  List<Long> getMostPopularDrinksIds();
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation to your answer. Answer with explanation will serve better for anyone who visits this question later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `join` in query and class projection to map your data

Fetch only Id and count

```
@Query("select new com.example.dto.DrinkDTO(dr.id, sum(ci.count)) from CartItem ci join ci.drink dr " 
       + "group by dr.id order by sum(ci.count) DESC")
Page<DrinkDTO> getMostPopularDrinks(Pageable pageable);
```

Projection class

```
class DrinkDTO {
   
   private Integer drinkId;

   private long count;
   
   public DrinkDTO(Integer drinkId, long count) {
      this.drinkId = drinkId;
      this.count = count;
   }       

   // getter, setter
}
```

Fetch Drink enity with count

```
@Query("select new com.example.dto.DrinkDTO(dr, sum(ci.count)) from CartItem ci join ci.drink dr " 
       + "group by dr order by sum(ci.count) DESC")
Page<DrinkDTO> getMostPopularDrinks(Pageable pageable);
```

Projection class

```
class DrinkDTO {
   
   private Drink drink;

   private long count;
   
   public DrinkDTO(Drink drink, long count) {
     this.drink = drink;
     this.count = count;
  }  
   //getter, setter
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it gives the error expected "(". Have you checked the query?

Comment: @ArturVartanyan Sorry I missed the new keyword, check now. And here `com.example.dto.DrinkDTO` is example use your own package.

Comment: And constructor is with all args?

Comment: Yes all argument constructor

Comment: (dr, sum(ci.count)) - 'Cannot resolve constructor 'ru.coffeetearea.dto.NewDrinkDTO(ru.coffeetearea.model.Drink, java.lang.Long)''

Comment: Can you show full stack trace in https://pastebin.pl/, may be type mismatch I changed count into Integer

Comment: An Intelij Idea tells me about error...when I hover mouse cursor on this code: `(dr, sum(ci.count))`

Comment: Did you run the code ? Then you get exact error if exist

Comment: I want to add log errors in Pastebin, but web-app Pastebin is not load

Comment: Then attatched in your post, and I added id with count fetch solution as your sql query you can try that also. I tested both working for me.

Comment: Please cross-check both solution query and constructor again now (type and constructor need to be exact parameter order), I tested both solutions it's perfectly worked for me.

Comment: May be you skype or telegram?

Comment: I am available in Google Meet

Comment: I did it a little differently and it worked for me! True, I began to return its id instead of a drink, but nothing, I think, and so good. Thank you for your help!